# Vue Passing the result in a function to parse the date

Tags: vue.js, date, parsing

I want to pass the result of **currentView.lastSuccessRunDate** so I can do some operations and return the result in the table instead of the direct API response. Is that possible in VUE ? A function that would take this response as a parameter and return an edited output?

```
 <tr
      class="bg-gray-100 border-b border-gray-200"
      v-for="currentView in getDashboard()"
      :key="currentView.id"
    >

   <td class="px-4 py-3">N/A</td>
    <td class="px-4 py-3">{{currentView.name}}</td>
     <td class="px-4 py-3">{{currentView.lastSuccessRunDate}} </td>
     <td class="px-4 py-3">{{currentView.lastFailedRunDate}}</td>
  <td class="px-4 py-3">{{currentView.lastRunDuration}}</td>
    </tr>
```

**Solution(Pretty obvious of course):-**

{{ calculateDateIntervels(currentView.lastSuccessRunDate) }}

and used moment library. Very effective.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use filter

https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

```
Vue.filter('capitalize', function (value) {
  if (!value) return ''
  value = value.toString()
  return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
})

<td class="px-4 py-3">{{currentView.lastSuccessRunDate | capitalize }} </td>
```

Comment: I used the moment.js library. It did the job! Thanks alot though. I believe this answer also works